# Accessing a Rails Engine model from within a namespaced controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Rails Engine model that looks something like this:

```
module Adhocracy
  class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  . . .
  end
end
```

So I would expect to be able to access it with `Adhocracy::Membership`. However, I'm getting an error in this namespaced controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class Adhocracy::MembershipsController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @memberships = Adhocracy::Membership.where(params)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The error is:

```
uninitialized constant Api::V1::Adhocracy::Membership
```

If I go into this controller with debugger and type in `Adhocracy`, it returns `Api::V1::Adhocracy`, while `Adhocracy::Membership` returns the above error. However, if I go into another controller with debugger (such as `Api::V1::SessionsController`), `Adhocracy::Membership` returns the expected model. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to how Ruby works: it first searches in your current classes, then in its ancestors.

So `Adhocracy` matches `Api::V1::Adhocracy` in your `MembershipsController` and it searches `Membership` there.

Whereas in another controller with no match, the search goes down the ancestor tree until it reaches `Object` where `Adhocracy` is defined.

To be sure to get top level constants append `::` which leads you to: `::Adhocracy::Membership`